# OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python Practice\speak_function2.py", line 21, in <module>
    takecommand()
  File "e:\Python Practice\speak_function2.py", line 12, in takecommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 138, in __enter__
    self.audio.open(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

Comment: Can you please add your code and information about the context when this happened? Including the full traceback is good but it's not enough to guess what is happening

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.